# How do I assign CSS class based on state variable's value in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Im coding up a project in ReactJS. Ive got some divs that can be clicked by user. By default every div's background color should be set to green, but after the click it should become red (meaning that this specific div has been already clicked and further clicking on it won't make any difference). My idea for setting the CSS class is that inside className I've got a ternary if statement based on corresponding value from the array. The solution I've presented doesn't do anything, no errors are popping up. How can I achieve my goal?

Code:

```
var style = require('./board.css');

var React = require('react');

class board extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            fieldClicksArray: [
                false, false, false, 
                false, false, false, 
                false, false, false
            ]
        }
    }

    handleClick(index) {
      if (this.state.fieldClicksArray[index] === false) {
          this.state.fieldClicksArray[index] = true;
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div className="parent">
                    <div className={this.state.fieldClicksArray[0] ? 'red' : 'green'} onClick={() => this.handleClick(0)}>1</div>
            </div>//parent
        )//return
    }//render
}//class

export default board;
```

The CSS:

```
.red {
    background-color: red;
}

.green {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `setState()`. And clone the array so that you don't mutate the previous state. Finally, it is better to use the functional form of `setState()` when your next state is calculated from previous state.

```
handleClick(index) {
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    // make a copy
    let fieldClicksArray = prevState.fieldClicksArray.slice();
    // change one item
    fieldsClickArray[index] = true;
    // return next state to be merged
    return { fieldsClickArray };
  });
}
```

Read more: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately same here. The div gets its red background color, but it changes on render - user dont have the chance to click it themself, because while the page renders the div is already red. Inside onClick I used arrow function so it shouldn't trigger immediately, right?

Answer (score 1):

```js
class Board extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            fieldClicksArray: [
                false, false, false, 
                false, false, false, 
                false, false, false
            ]
        }
    }

    handleClick(index) {
      if (this.state.fieldClicksArray[index] === false) {
          var newArray = this.state.fieldClicksArray;
          newArray[index] = true;

          this.setState({
              fieldClicksArray: newArray
           })
           }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="parent">
                <div className={this.state.fieldClicksArray[0] ? 'red' : 'green'} onClick= {()=>this.handleClick(0)}>1</div>
        </div>//parent
        )//return
    }//render
}//class

ReactDOM.render(<Board />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

```css
.red {
    background-color: red;
}

.green {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

`this.state.fieldClicksArray[index] = true;` wont perform anything. you need to call `this.setState` to change the state of your component.

```
handleClick(index) {
      if (this.state.fieldClicksArray[index] === false) {
          var newArray = this.state.fieldClicksArray;
          newArray[index] === false;

          this.setState({
              fieldClicksArray: newArray
           })
    }
```

Also to use `setState` method in your click handler, you'll need to bind your function to the component,

```
 render () {
        return (
            <div className="parent">
                <div className={this.state.fieldClicksArray[0] ? 'red' : 'green'} onClick= {()=>this.handleClick(0)}>1</div>
        </div>//parent
        )//return
    }
```

Comment: I believe in this line:
`newArray[index] === false;` you wanted to set it to true. Ive changed that. Also, Ive tried your suggestion and still nothing changes and no errors show up

Comment: @AleksanderSadaj There were some syntax error. I have removed them. Please see the snippets.

Comment: This modifies state directly since you're operating on the original array.

Comment: Good news is that your code works, but bad news is that it triggers the handleClick function on render, despite the arrow function inside onClick. Why does it happen this way? How can we avoid it?

Comment: @AleksanderSadaj No, it doesn't. Please run the code snippet and refer to the code in snippet.

Comment: I ran the code snippet immediately after reading it, but when I use your code in my app then it still triggers instantly on render. is it fault of my system or anything?